# Launching Google Maps with more parameters

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, marker

I have read a lot of stuff about launching Google Maps in Android.

That's pretty easy:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:38.899533,-77.036476");
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(it);
```

The problem is that the map is shown at a high zoom level and there is no marker on the map.
So, if the user move a little bit or something happen, the point is lost.

Is that possible to add a marker like this:

http://img.skitch.com/20100820-da3n4r7h5xbsu6bsx4p4ujjghc.jpg

or like this:

http://img.skitch.com/20100820-qg7k2m5wtwm3j5phphrgc8tb53.jpg

So i can be sure that even if the user move the map, he will be able to find this place again.

Thank a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem that the correct answer is no, and I have currently no workaround...

Answer (score 0):

The geo: scheme can take a zoom level:

geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom

but as far as I know, you can't specify a marker in the intent.

If you use this mode of the geo: scheme, it might give you what you want:

geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=business+near+city